# A standard way to name the base/root Java class in Swing application

Tags: java, swing

What should I name my base or root Java class in Swing application?

Right now my project is called `FirstSwingProject` followed by src folder and a package named base.

But my main class is called PaneFactory.java because the idea is that I am creating a Swing app that will open new sticky notes.

Can anyone suggest a better name for this class?

Is there a Java naming convention out there for the first class?

Comment: I'd call it `StickyNotes.java`

Comment: I did end up calling it StickyNotes.java! It was a tough decision because I agree with the com.domain.project naming convention I just could not see it for my first Swing/Java project. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no conventions but personally I usually name my base class the same or similar as the name I intend on using for my program||app.
So in your case maybe NoteReader or something?

or as somebody else suggested just Main.java

Answer (score 6):

I would call it

```
com.yourdomainname.yourprojectname.Main
```

There is no naming convention for "Main" classes. Classes are spelt with CamelCase, and should always be in a package. The convention for packages it to prefix them with your domain name in the inverse order. So if your domain name is jojo.com, it should be

```
com.jojo.yourprojectname.Main
```